# Why am I not getting proper logs in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

when testing my Lambda function. I always just get this error, this obviously does not help debugging:

```
    OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
START RequestId: a22379c9-427c-45ab-bfd5-c166bf507418 Version: $LATEST
2023-04-29T15:45:42.496Z a22379c9-427c-45ab-bfd5-c166bf507418 Task timed out after 600.11 seconds

END RequestId: a22379c9-427c-45ab-bfd5-c166bf507418
REPORT RequestId: a22379c9-427c-45ab-bfd5-c166bf507418  Duration: 600108.83 ms  Billed Duration: 601489 ms  Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 154 MB Init Duration: 1379.93 ms
```

The function executes a docker container based of an image on ECR.

My lambda function handler looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
from time import sleep 
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import date 
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import boto3
from io import BytesIO

COLUMNS = [<<list of columns for the pandas df>> ]

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Referer": "https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-64759120",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,lt;q=0.8,et;q=0.7,de;q=0.6"}

KEYWORDS  = [ <<list of keywords>>]

def make_get_request(max_retries, URL):

    session = requests.Session()
    retry = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=max_retries)
    session.mount('https://', retry)
    session.mount('http://', retry)
    
    try:
        response = session.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
        return response
    
    except (ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as err:
        print(f"Failed to connect to the API, retrying... Error: {err}")
        make_get_request(max_retries)
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects as err:
        print("Bad URL, try a different one")
        raise SystemExit(err)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        raise SystemExit(err)


def get_pages()->int:

    BASE_URL="https://www.stepstone.de/jobs/data-engineer?action=facet_selected%3bage%3bage_1&ag=age_1"

    response = make_get_request(3, BASE_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 

    result_tag = soup.find('span', 'res-kyg8or at-facet-header-total-results')
    results = result_tag.text
    results = results.replace(".", "")
    pages = math.ceil(int(results)/25)

    return pages 


def extract_job_cards(title, days, i):

    URL = f"https://www.stepstone.de/jobs/{title}?page_selected={i}&action=facet_selected%3bage%3bage_{days}&ag=age_{days}"
    response = make_get_request(3, URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
    cards = soup.find_all('article', 'res-iibro8')

    return cards 


def request_job_description(href):
        DESCRIPTION_LINK = "https://www.stepstone.de" + href
        response_details = make_get_request(3, DESCRIPTION_LINK)

        return response_details


def extract_keywords(card):

    atag = card.h2.a

    title_card = atag.div
    title_card_str = title_card.text
    title = title_card_str.split("</div></div></div>")[0]
    print(title)
    company_name = card.div.span.text
    href = atag["href"]
    occured_keywords = []


    response_soup = BeautifulSoup(request_job_description(href).text, 'html.parser')
    boxes = response_soup.find_all('div', 'listing-content-provider-10ltcrf')
    if len(boxes)==4:
        del boxes[0]
        del boxes[-1]
    
    for box in boxes:
        text = box.find('span', 'listing-content-provider-pz58b2').get_text()
        for keyword in KEYWORDS:
            if keyword.upper() in text.upper():
                occured_keywords.append(keyword.upper())

        occured_keywords = list(dict.fromkeys(occured_keywords))

    return occured_keywords, title, href, company_name

def append_to_df(occured_keywords, job_df, title, company_name, href):

    job_dict = {
        "LOADED_AT": date.today(),
        "JOB_TITLE": title,
        "COMPANY": company_name,
        "HREF_LINK": href,
        'PYTHON': 0
#There are obviously more key value pairs bit I left them out of #this post for simplicity reasons 
    }

    for skill in occured_keywords:
        job_dict[skill] = 1

    row = []
    for value in job_dict.values():
        row.append(value)

    job_df.loc[len(job_df)] = row


def extract_and_append_skills(cards, job_df):

    for card in cards:
        if all(job not in card.h2.a.div.text for job in ["Data Engineer", "DWH", "Data Warehouse", "ETL", "Analytics Engineer", "Business Intelligence", "Data Platform", "Data Architekt", "Data Architect"]):
            continue
        else:
            keywords, title, href, company_name = extract_keywords(card)
            append_to_df(keywords, job_df, title, company_name, href)


    def main(event, context):    
    
        job_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUMNS)
        try:
            for i in range(get_pages()):
                cards = extract_job_cards('data-engineer', 1, i)
                extract_and_append_skills(cards, job_df)
            job_df = job_df[~job_df.duplicated(subset=['HREF_LINK'])].copy()
            print(len(job_df))

            return "Success"
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

The Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
  
COPY stepstone_scraper.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -t "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

RUN chmod 644 $(find . -type f)
RUN chmod 755 $(find . -type d)

CMD ["stepstone_scraper.main"]
```

The lambda function creation in terraform like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "job_scraping_function" {
package_type  = "Image"
image_uri     = "${aws_ecr_repository.scraping_repo.repository_url}:latest"
function_name = "job_scraping_function"
role = aws_iam_role.lambda_s3_role.arn
memory_size  = 256
timeout      = 600
depends_on = [null_resource.docker_build_and_push]
}
```

The underlying role can be assumed by lambda, has full s3, ec2, lambda, ECR and cloudwatch access and the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole arn is attached to it.

Has anyone got an idea what my issue might be?

Comment: Please show the rest of your function's code. What is `extract_job_cards()`? What is `get_pages()`? What is `extract_and_append_skills()`? In your handler you are only printing/logging something at the very end, right before you return a response. Something is hanging and causing a timeout before that, so all you are seeing is the initial invocation log, and the timeout log. The current logs are **exactly** what I would expect giving the code you have shown, so I'm not sure why you think your issue is a logging problem. Your issue is a timeout problem.

Comment: The code works perfectly when I run it on my local machine and only takes about a minute. I have added the rest of the code

Comment: Is the CPU architecture of your local machine the same as the one you are using for Lambda?

Comment: The code that you show has very little logging. I recommend adding `print()` statements *before* any actions that the function takes, certainly *before* any functions called in your main handler. Also verify that you have the correct permissions (granted by the "basic execution role" managed policy) to write those log messages to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't logging hardly anything, so I would expect the exact logs you are seeing. You need to add more logs to see what is happening before the timeout. This is not an issue of "getting proper logs", it is an issue of your Lambda function timing out.

The reason it is timing out is most likely because the network requests you are making don't work from the Lambda environment. Most likely you have configured the Lambda function to run in a VPC, without deploying it to a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway. If that's not the case, then the URL you are trying to access on the Internet may have blocked AWS IPs.

Comment: After having done a few tests, I can say that the Url has blocked AWS IP's. Is there a way of dealing with this apart from using a proxy server?

Comment: From a purely AWS perspective, no, there is no way of dealing with that. And if the people that own that URL don't want you hitting it from AWS, then you might want to reach out to them about getting access instead of just trying to bypass their security controls. It also looks like you are spoofing the User-Agent and Referrer HTTP headers in this bot you are writing, which is acting in bad faith. Bots that spoof things like that instead of identifying themselves is exactly why people revert to blocking entire cloud services from accessing their website.